# How to retrieve regularisation term from xgboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

To evaluate the bias-variance tradeoff, I prefer to plot the prediction error vs. the complexity of the trained estimator.
[error vs complexity plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpqa6.jpg)

In case of xgboost [the documentation states that the complexity is taken as the regularisation term of the objective function](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html). So in principle it should be easy to generate such a plot.

However, I can't figure out how to retrieve the calculated regularisation term for the trained model. I am using the Python scikit-learn API.

Is this value available in the library, or should it be recomputed after training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve, instead you need to set regularization. As lower regularization, as more complex model and vice versa. In case of the XGBoost the regularization is lambda ([a link for the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html)).

You need to iterate through the list of the `l2` values, train the model and calculate the error for the training and test subsets.

Also here is [good article](https://medium.com/data-design/xgboost-hi-im-gamma-what-can-i-do-for-you-and-the-tuning-of-regularization-a42ea17e6ab6) how to tune the regularizationn for XGBoost.